# Order Currency codes by name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how can i order my currency codes by name. In data base i have Id and Code(name),and currently they are order by Id. I want to order them by name ASC.
Down is my C# code in ASP.NET

```
namespace Portal.Framework.Mvc.ViewDataPreparers
{
  public class CurrenciesCodesPreparer : ActionFilterAttribute, IDataPreparer<Currency>
  {
    public IList<Currency> GetDataItems()
    {
      return DefaultContainerReference.Resolve<IGlobalizationService>().GetAllCurrencies().CurrencyList;
    }

    public static string ViewDataKey { get { return "CurrenciesCodes"; } }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      filterContext.Controller.ViewData[ViewDataKey] = GetDataItems().ToSelectableList(true, Resources.Default_All, null, null, "Id", "Code");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried OrderBy?`    return DefaultContainerReference.Resolve<IGlobalizationService>().GetAllCurrencies().CurrencyList.OrderBy(x=>x.Code);`

Answer (score 0):

It is quit simple.

```
var currency = getallCurrency();
var sortByName = currency.OrderBy(x=>x.CurrenyName);
```

you can do like this.

Comment: Where you return the currency. you asked how i can order curreny by name.. It means you already return the currency data. Just add this logic to there.