# Want to order Currency by name ASC in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to ordey my currency codes(names) by name, and not by id.

I have in database Id and Code for every Currency.

In asp.net I have this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using IGP.Presentation.BOPortalFacade;
using Portal.Framework.Mvc.Extensions;
using IGP.Common.Windsor;
using IGP.Presentation.BOPortalFacade.DTOs.GlobalizationService;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Portal.Framework.Services.Resources;

namespace Portal.Framework.Mvc.ViewDataPreparers
{
  public class CurrenciesCodesPreparer : ActionFilterAttribute, IDataPreparer<Currency>
  {
    public IList<Currency> GetDataItems()
    {
      return DefaultContainerReference.Resolve<IGlobalizationService>().GetAllCurrencies().CurrencyList;
    }

    public static string ViewDataKey { get { return "CurrenciesCodes"; } }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      filterContext.Controller.ViewData[ViewDataKey] = GetDataItems().ToSelectableList(true, Resources.Default_All, null, null, "Id", "Code");
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to add following code

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewData[ViewDataKey] = GetDataItems().OrderBy(x => x.Code).ToSelectableList(true, Resources.Default_All, null, null, "Id", "Code");
```

at the end but there is error.See in the attached image[image]

ToSelectableList has this code:

```
public static IList<SelectListItem> ToSelectableList<T>(
      this IList<T> items,
      bool addDefaultItem = true,
      string defaultItemName = DefaultItemName,
      int? defaultItemValue = DefaultItemValue,
      object selectedItemValue = null,
      string defaultDataValueField = DefaultDataValueField,
      string defaultDataTextField = DefaultDataTextField,
      bool selectAllItems = false)
    {
      // resolve from resources
      if (defaultItemValue.Equals(DefaultItemName))
        defaultItemName = Resources.GetResourceValue(AllResourceKey);

      var resultList = new List<SelectListItem>();
      if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
      {
        var itemSelectList = new SelectList(items, defaultDataValueField, defaultDataTextField, selectedItemValue);

        resultList =
          itemSelectList.Select(
            x =>
            new SelectListItem
              {
                Text = x.Text.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Value = x.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
              }).ToList();
      }

      if ((selectAllItems) && (!addDefaultItem) && (selectedItemValue == null)) //in case you have multi select
      {
        foreach (var selectListItem in resultList)
        {
          selectListItem.Selected = true;
        }
      }

      if (addDefaultItem)
      {
        resultList.Insert(
          0,
          new SelectListItem { Text = defaultItemName, Value = defaultItemValue == null ? "" : defaultItemValue.ToString() });
      }

      return resultList;
    }
```

Comment: I think that `ToSelectableList` is yours, not framework code. Apparently, it doesn't work with Ordered Enumerables. But since I can't see its definition, I can't offer much in the way of help.

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: Did you post your question [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968743/order-currency-codes-by-name) ?

Comment: yes, but here is the whole code and it's better writen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension `ToSelectableList()` accepting first argument of type `IList<>` not of `IOrderedEnumerable<>`. You should rewrite your extension definition as

```
public static IList<SelectListItem> ToSelectableList<T>(
      this IEnumerable<T> items,
      bool addDefaultItem = true,
      string defaultItemName = DefaultItemName,
      int? defaultItemValue = DefaultItemValue,
      object selectedItemValue = null,
      string defaultDataValueField = DefaultDataValueField,
      string defaultDataTextField = DefaultDataTextField,
      bool selectAllItems = false)
```

So, it will not throw error on usage with `IOrderedEnumerable<>`

Comment: I get error: Operater '>' cannot be applied to operands of type' method group' and 'int' . In this code is the error items.Count > 0

Comment: use .Any() or .Count() > 0 instead of .Count > 0